# NSMutableArray appears empty but is being populated

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

Am having a major problem with an NSMutableArray, I'm probably missing something really obvious - have probably been looking at it so much that I just can't see it.

Am reading some Tweets and then using the results to populate an NSMutableArray :

```
@synthesize testArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad{

        [super viewDidLoad];

        testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.jsonq=kennedy&with_twitter_user_id=true&result_type=recent"]
        parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

       [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
       {
        if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {

            // The response from Twitter is in JSON format
            // Move the response into a dictionary
            NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
            NSArray *results = [dict objectForKey:@"results"];

            //Loop through the results
            for (NSDictionary *tweet in results) {

                tweetStore *tweetDetails = [[tweetStore alloc] init];
                NSString *twitText = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];

                //Save the tweet to the twitterText array
                tweetDetails.name = @"test";
                tweetDetails.date = @"test";
                tweetDetails.tweet = twitText;

                [testArray addObject:tweetDetails];
            }

            tweetStore *retrieveTweet = (tweetStore*)[testArray objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"tweet is: %@", retrieveTweet.tweet);
            //NSLog(@"Array is: %@", testArray); - *can* view Array etc here
        }

         else {
               NSLog(@"Twitter error, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
         }
    }
     ];


    NSLog(@"test array: %@", testArray); //Array is now empty......
}
```

I can view the array within the code where I've marked it, retrieve the objects I want etc, it works perfectly. But as soon as I try to access or display anything from the array outside of this then it seems to be empty. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You're making an async call using a callback block. When the request is done, the array will be populated, but you check it right after setting up the call to be done "sometime in the future", not after getting a response.

Comment: I agree with @JoachimIsaksson; it's a timing issue.

Comment: its getting released/deallocated..

Comment: Yeah, the way to handle it is to have code inside your callback block somehow "notify" the rest of your app that new data is available.  For a table view app, eg, it might trigger `reload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code in the block is performed in an asynchronous way, so it is executed **after** the NSLog code.

The code executed follows this flow:

- First you perform the initialization:

  ```
  [super viewDidLoad];

  testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.jsonq=kennedy&with_twitter_user_id=true&result_type=recent"]
  parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
  ```
- You start the request:

  ```
  [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) { <block_code> } ];
  ```
- You print array information and it is empty (correct):

  ```
  NSLog(@"test array: %@", testArray);
  ```

Now the asynchronous request ends and the code in the block is executed: so the array is populated correctly only in the block code.